# Macro para importar txt de ancho fijo

Tags: vba, macros, txt

Como estan todos,

Tengo una inquietud,

Como puedo realizar de manera automatizada la importación de un archivo .txt que tiene la caracteristica delimitada de ancho fijo.
Lo he visto para hacerlo con una macro pero al final no me imprta nada.

Gracias por su ayuda
Saludos

Comment: Podrías agregar a la pregunta la macro que intentaste y no funcionó? Y para importar en dónde, en Excel o qué?

Answer (score 1):

Independientemente de que deberías haber añadido el código de esa macro que viste pero no funciona te cuento: hay varias formas de hacer esa importación pero si no quieres complicarte la vida lo mejor es que, con la grabadora de macros, te grabes importando ese archivo y revises su código. Básicamente verás algo como esto:

```
Sub Importa_txt()
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;Z:\ruta_de_tu_archivo\volumetrias.txt" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "volumetrias"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 1252
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlFixedWidth
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(9, 1, 1, 9, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileFixedColumnWidths = Array(1, 7, 39, 13, 19, 20, 51, 47, 11, 15, 11, 15, 15, 10, _
        18)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

La orden ".TextFileColumnDataTypes" indica qué columnas del fichero original se incluyen en la importación final. Un 9 para NO importarla y un 1 para importar.
La instrucción ".TextFileFixedColumnWidths" se utiliza para indicar el tamaño en caracteres de cada columna. Por ejemplo la primera columna tendría un tamaño de 1 caracter, la segunda columna de 7 caracteres, la tercer de 39 caracteres y así con todas.

Comment: Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda